# PVLIB: AMY weather dataset with PVLIB

Tags: pvlib

I was wondering process of loading the actual meteorological data (AMY) weather dataset with PVlib. Should we use pvlib.iotools.read_tmy3 function for loading AMY data as well or is there specialized function/method of loading AMY weather dataset?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions only care about the format of the data, not the data itself. So if your AMY data is in TMY format, then using the TMY reader is appropriate.